# Geoserver layer error

Tags: xml, layer, geoserver

I added a new shapefile and a new layer but when i try to preview the layer with OpenLayer i get an xml to download containing:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException code="Internal error ">
      java.lang.NullPointerException
null
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I am a beginner with GeoServer, can anyone please provide some directions? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Never got the hang of it but playing around with it I found that when this error pops up you can clear it by restarting geoserver and rebuilding caches, or removing the layer, restarting geoserver and adding the layer again. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your description is missing some input. First, have you tried to preview your layer with the geoserver preview function? Sometimes geoserver makes funny things when adding new layers. SO you must verify first, that your layer works properly.

After that which protocol do you use to communicate with your server? WFS,WCS,WMS 1.0/1.1 ?

Comment: I did try to preview the layer using geoserver's preview (Layer Preview-> OpenLayers) and instead of returing the html with the layer preview it returns the xml mentioned in the first post.

Comment: By the way the shapefiles are fine, sice i can opent them with uDig

Answer (score 1):

Your Shapefile might have null values for the attribute(if style files is accessing that attribute to preview). You can edit the attributes before publishing the shape file, and republish. I think it solves your problem.

Sesu64